# How to load hook for particular controller

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-routing

I am new in codeigniter. I want to load hooks for admin panel controller.

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'][] = array(
    'class'    => 'AdminData',
    'function' => 'myfunction',
    'filename' => 'loginhelp.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks',
    'params'   => array()
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `post_controller_constructor` hook gets called after a `$class` is loaded.  The class that gets loaded is based on the route parameters.

**system/core/Codeigniter.php**

```
/**
 *<code>
 *  http://example.com/adminData/method
 *</code>
 *
 * $CI = new adminData(); => application/controllers/adminData.php
**/
$CI = new $class();

$EXT->call_hook('post_controller_constructor');
```

So if you wanted to call a method on the `adminData` controller, you could do something like this.

This method is not ideal, as its not very OOP like, however the way CI is built from a design point of view, you have to do a few workarounds like the example below

**application/controllers/adminData.php**

```
class AdminData extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){}

    // This cannot be called directly in the browser
    public function _filter()
    {
        /**
         * Put your logic in here
         *<code>
         * $this->model->logic()
         *</code>
        **/
        exit('I have just be called!');
    }
}
```

**application/hooks/loginhelp.php**

```
class AdminData
{
    protected $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        global $CI;
        $this->ci = $CI;
    }

    public function myfunction()
    {
        // If the class is not == AdminData, just bail
        if(get_class($this->ci) != 'AdminData') return;

        if(!is_callable(array($this->ci, '_filter'))) return;

        //calls $AdminData->_filter()
        return call_user_func(array($this->ci, '_filter'));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Ok this is the simplest way to do this:

> **declare a public variable in your Controller**

```
public $is_hookable = TRUE;
```

> **Then inside your hook function do this:**

```
$ci=&get_instance();

if($ci->is_hookable){
  ... enter whatever you want here;
}
```

hope this was helpful

Answer (score 3):

please read the document clearly https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html

> The hooks feature can be globally enabled/disabled by setting the
>   following item in the application/config/config.php file:

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

> Hooks are defined in application/config/hooks.php file.

You cannot load it for specific controller.You need to check controller name at hooks function and write code.  suppose your `post_controller_constructor` hooks function name is `myfunction` you can check it inside the function

```
 $CI =& get_instance();
 if($CI ->router->class=="AdminData"){//write your code}
```

Comment: I know dear.. Bt how to load for specific controller . Not for all

Answer (score 1):

```
    Application/config/hooks.php

    $hook['post_controller'] = array(
            'class'    => 'LogoutBlockedUser',
            'function' => 'logout',
            'filename' => 'LogoutBlockedUser.php',
            'filepath' => 'hooks',
            'params'   => ""
    );

    Enable hooks in config.php
    $config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;

    Application/hooks/LogoutBlockedUser.php

    class LogoutBlockedUser {


    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $CI =& get_instance();
        if(!(empty($CI->session->userdata('user_id'))))
        {
            $CI->load->model('Your_model', 'web');
            $result = $CI->common->select_query;
            if(!empty($result))
            {
                $CI->session->unset_userdata('user_id');
                session_destroy();
                redirect(base_url() . 'yourcontroller/function');
            }
        }

    }

}
```