# Run PHP Script that requirs login using cronjob

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am using CI hooks to prevent access to application without logging in,
But i am also using cron jobs to do some schedule task, now i don't need login to schedule task,

below is my code for controller used for hook,

```
public function checkSession()
{
    if($this->CI->router->fetch_class() == "cron")
    {
         //How should i continue with Cron class??
    }
    elseif($this->CI->router->fetch_class() != "login")
    {
         // session check logic here...change this accordingly
         if($this->CI->session->userdata['user_id'] == '' )
         {
             redirect('login');
         }
    }
}
```

Now i want cron class to run without checking user session and login,

How can i continue to cron class in If condition?

Or any other thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: What is being executed to trigger the cronjob?  You have a cronjob defined in your crontab on the server?

Comment: @Clayton, Yes its on server, wget http:/my/domain.com/cron

Comment: than just call the function of cron class self::index();

Comment: Try [this](http://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-33378.html) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29296015/how-to-load-hook-for-particular-controller). [Google](https://www.google.ba/search?q=codeigniter+hooks+exclude+some+controller&oq=codeigniter+hooks+exclude+some+controller&aqs=chrome..69i57.34175j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) gave those solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The Secure behavior is to login even if you are running the script using a cronjob, and this is doable using cURL for example, where you can use your credentials to create a session, login normally and execute the scripts according to the privileges you have.

You may refer to the following thread for more details:
[Using curl with a username and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594880/using-curl-with-a-username-and-password)

Answer (score 0):

Other options if you insist on keeping things simple and security is not a big issue for you, You may either pass a parameter when you call the script by cronjob as mentioned in the link:
[passing a command-line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854297/how-to-determine-if-a-php-file-is-loaded-via-cron-command-line)

Or you may refer to the PHP basic techniques as mentioned in the link:
[detect if script is run from a cron job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/190759/can-php-detect-if-its-run-from-a-cron-job-or-from-the-command-line)